# Can I autowire only one among multiple arguments for constructor injection?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor, autowired

I have a bean, into which I wanted to inject an array of **Resources**.

```
org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]
```

Actually, an array of **InputStreamSource** was good enough. I wanted my bean definition to look something like:

```
<bean id="..." class="com.usta.SomeClass">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:somedir/*.xml"/>
</bean>
```

where my constructor was:

```
public SomeClass(InputStreamSource[] sources);
```

Since that wouldn't work, I reluctantly chose to have

```
public SomeClass(InputStreamSource[] sources, ResourcePatternResolver resolver);
```

But now how can I inject the **ApplicationContext** (which is a **ResourcePatternResolver**) into this bean via constructor injection? Or can I say only auto-wire this constructor argument?

I know Setter Injection (with **ResourceLoaderAware**) would solve this but I am sticking to Consructor Injections as far as possible.

**SomeClass** uses the **Resources** some initialization up front; with setter injection I will have to defer initialization and not be able to declare a number of **SomeClass**'s fields **final**.

Comment: Have you tried marking the constructor as @Autowired?

Comment: Why not create for example new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver() ?

Comment: @mrembisz I am indeed using that. But thought hey why not just inject the ApplicationContext. I only need to use the resolver once, so why create a new one?

Comment: @mrembisz I am using it for UnitTesting though. I try to avoid AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests as far as possible.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, well how'd I autowire when I do need to input the path string too?

Comment: @UstamanSangat if you mix XML and @Autowired it should work. XML for the paths, `@Autowired` for the ApplicationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you ...

Constructor:

```
public SomeClass(final Resource[] resources) { ... }
```

Configuration:

```
<bean id="patternResolver" class="org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver" />

<bean id="..." class="com.usta.SomeClass">
    <constructor-arg value="#{patternResolver.getResources('somedir/*.xml')}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Just the same response I had to mrembisz: I am indeed using that. But thought hey why not just inject the ApplicationContext. I only need to use the resolver once, so why create a new one?

Comment: @UstamanSangat I understand, but I think there's a "chicken and egg" problem here: in the process of building the ApplicationContext you'd invoke a constructor that has it as a reference. Maybe that's why there doesn't seem to be an easy way to reference the ApplicationContext itself in the configuration file. The other approaches, for example implementing ApplicationContextAware or auto-wiring, leave you with Spring-specific references in your class and/or don't involve the constructor (so no final instance fields). So I don't think creating a separate pattern resolver object is so bad.